# Insert WYSIWYG editor text in the database

Tags: php, editor, wysiwyg

I'm a beginner in PHP, I want to make a page containing WYSIWYG editor and the text tiped in the editor will be displayed in another page. The question is : how to insert the text with its attributes (bold-italic-image...) in the database to show it in the other page? Just like the text editor that we use here on stackoverflow to post questions.

Comment: Classes and CSS my friend ... classes and CSS.

Comment: Have you checked the well known WYSIWYG-s, they have example codes. http://www.tinymce.com/ , http://ckeditor.com/ , http://imperavi.com/redactor/

Answer (score 0):

Create a form. Put a textarea in it. Then use one of the WYSIWYG scripts to turn the textarea into an editor. When you submit the form, it will send the html code of the WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 0):

WYSIWYG Editors actually build on top of basic HTML Editing functionality that the browsers already have built in.

to create a WYSIWYG editor you need to use javascript

Read More Here

[JQuery Based Text Editors](http://superdit.com/2011/05/21/12-jquery-based-rich-text-editor/)

for storing the data you can simply use html tags

ie..

the data look something like this

```
<P>This is a test</P> <h1>for a question</h1>
```

and you can retrieve the data using 
php echo or print

```
<?php print "<P>This is a test</P> <h1>for a question</h1> " ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the datatype to TEXT for your textarea field. And use a form like this.

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
 <textarea class="myEditor" name="description"></textarea>
 <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>

<?php
 if(isset($_POST) !empty($_POST)){
 //Place your insert query here
}
?>
```